# How to generate swc from swf or abc files

Tags: c++, c, cygwin, alchemy

How can i generate swc files from swf or abs been made with avm2 assembly adobe alchemy compiler.

this code generated the swf and the abc files :

```
java -Xms16M -Xmx4096M -jar D:/alchemy/bin/asc.jar -AS3 -strict \
-import  D:/alchemy/flashlibs/global.abc \
-import D:/alchemy/flashlibs/playerglobal.abc \
-config Alchemy::Debugger=false \
-config Alchemy::NoDebugger=true -config Alchemy::Shell=false \
-config Alchemy::NoShell=true -config Alchemy::LogLevel=0 \
-config Alchemy::Vector=true -config Alchemy::NoVector=false \
-config Alchemy::SetjmpAbuse=false \
-swf cmodule.openttd.ConSprite,800,600,60 xxx.as
```

does anybody know how to use any option in this code to make swc.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `-swc` instead of `-swf`.  By the way, you should really move on from Alchemy to [FlasCC](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/flascc/).